# I want to return a JSON in a variable of multiple tables In SQL 2017

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I want to return a `JSON` in a variable of multiple tables In `SQL 2017`.

```
Create table TestingJson(ID int,FName varchar(20),LName varchar(20))
Insert into TestingJson(ID,FName,LName) Select 1,'Vishal','Mittal' union 
Select 2,'Kunal','Singh'

Select * from TestingJson for json path,Root('Data')
Select count(*)[Count] from TestingJson for json path,Root('DataCount')

Declare @UserData varchar(max)
select @UserData = (Select * from TestingJson for json path,Root('Data')) + ',' + (Select count(*)[Count] from TestingJson for json path,Root('DataCount'))
select @UserData
```

Result:-

```
{"Data":[{"ID":1,"Name":"Vishal"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Kunal"}]},{"DataCount":[{"Count":2}]}
```

This is not returning a object of json or this is not a correct format of json but I want only one object of json like this-

```
{
    "Data":[{
    "ID":1,"FName":"Vishal","LName":"Mittal"},{
    "ID":2,"FName":"Kunal","LName":"Singh"}],"DataCount":[{
    "Count":2}]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 
 (Select * from TestingJson for json path)[Data],
 (Select count(*)[Count] from TestingJson for json path)[DataCount]
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

It produces the required output

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "FName": "Vishal",
            "LName": "Mittal"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "FName": "Kunal",
            "LName": "Singh"
        }
    ],
    "DataCount": [
        {
            "Count": 2
        }
    ]
}
```